# Android + Gradle: Best place to set dynamic archivesBaseName

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In our Android project we want the filename of our APK to contain information such as the date, git branch name and short commit hash.

We've been setting this as part of our `defaultConfig`

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
      setProperty("archivesBaseName", "$projectName.$branchName.$date.$buildNumber.$versionCode-$versionName-$versionSha")    
   }
}
```

This works most of the time but our build sometimes fails with errors pointing to the value being stale (for example after switching branches). Forcing Gradle Sync in Android Studio usually fixes it.

So is there a better, more robust way of making sure that property stays up to date and forces a gradle sync, if necessary?

Comment: I ended up moving this out of gradle entirely, and doing it after build. Would love a proper answer to that though

Answer (score 2):

try to call `clean.execute()` before

```
android { ... }
```

it is the cheapest 'sync' task I can think of :)

```
   clean.execute()
   android {
       defaultConfig {
          setProperty("archivesBaseName", "$projectName.$branchName.$date.$buildNumber.$versionCode-$versionName-$versionSha")    
       }
    }
```

Comment: haha, crude, but I guess might "work". Still, would love something that's more of a "solution" than hack

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue, they were not always uptodate with the build.

I solved it by using:

```
project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "myAppName");
```

under the defaultConfig block, and I stopped having the problem.

Not sure it will work for the branch, build number or date, but it's worth giving it a shot.
Here's my configs, including the defaultConfig Block. For my case I was only using a hard coded versionName and  build Number (I call it versionCode because I set it in the manifest dynamically). But maybe you can tweak it to your needs:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22

    versionCode System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") as Integer ?: 0

    versionName "6.2.5." + versionCode

}
project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "myAppname" + defaultConfig.versionName);
```

Comment: it will not work!! `project.ext.set` remain cached until you sincronize the gradle file! if will throw random `.apk does not exist on disk`

Answer (score 0):

If an error occurs during the build process, the Messages window appears to describe the issue. Gradle may recommend some command-line options to help you resolve the issue, such as --stacktrace or --debug. To use command-line options with your build process:

1. Open the Settings or Preferences dialog: On Windows or Linux, select
   File > Settings from the main menu.
2. Navigate to Build, Execution,Deployment > Compiler.
3. In the text field next to Command-line Options, enter your command-line options.
4. Click OK to save and exit.

Gradle will apply these command-line options the next time you try building your app.

I have taken the information from [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html) page.

Comment: That doesn't address the problem. I know what the issue is - Gradle doesn't correctly detect the environment has changed (branch, date, stuff).

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to automatically detect the change and force gradle to re-sync. If I find a way to do it, I'll let you know.